# how to run never ending bash process in nodejs without locking up the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

The point of the server is to be able to pick a webcam and stream it, along with a few other things I already have working. I am trying to run a continuous process (mjpg-streamer) from within a node.js server. The node.js server is handling a serving a HTML page that has a select drop down binded to a javascript function to send a command to the server via socket.io. The drop down lets me select video0, video1, and none. However, whenever I try to run the server it refuses saying everything after the a particular block of code is unreachable or the code gets stuck running an infinite process. How can I execute this without locking up the server? Here is the code that causes the problem:

```
child = exec("video0.sh", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
sys.print('stdout: ' + stdout);
sys.print('stderr: ' + stderr);
if (error !== null) {
  console.log('exec error: ' + error);
}
```

The bash script video0.sh is:

```
cd mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer ;
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ;
./mjpg_streamer -o "output_http.so -w ./www -p 8080" -i "input_uvc.so -d /dev/video0
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `child_process.exec` documentation (emphasis mine):

> `callback` Function called with the output **when process terminates**

If you expect that program to stream data, it probably isn't terminating.  You will want to use `child_process.spawn`, which returns a `ChildProcess` object.  This gives you access to `stdout` and `stderr` as streams, which means that you can work with the data as it comes out rather than only once it is finished.

Comment: How would I do that? The data that is streaming is a live video stream directing itself to port 8080 as an html img.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I thought the video needed to go through the node server.  That said, this will stop the node.js server from locking up even if you just ignore the stdout/stderr streams.  The problem is that `child_process.exec` locks up the server until the process it creates is completed.